# How to create the necessary schema/tables in order to run such a script in Oracle 11g Express on windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, express, oracle11g, schema

I have a script which starts such as this (I cannot post it exactly as is):

```
    CREATE TABLE "X"."Y" 
    (   
     "A" NUMBER, 
     "B" NUMBER, 
     "C" NUMBER
    ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
    PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
    STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
    PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
```

I know that I need to create a schema(user) called X and I have. But when I login as X and run this script it fails giving the same error at every line-"table or view does not exist". The same thing happens if I login as SYSDBA and run the script.

I'm overwhelmed by this and starting to lose my mind. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: The code you've shown can't throw that error. (Unless you have created a DDL trigger which seems unlikely). 'At every line' doesn't make sense either. Is your entire script just that single create statement? How are you running the script?

Comment: To answer your first question, the script is creating multiple tables with similar create statements in the schema 'X'. I run it using the '@' command for oracle11g express using the cmd, since it doesn't have a GUI by default(even to create users which is key)!The error (which I found using a separately installed GUI to manage the oracle express db), was the schema/user X not having privilege to create stuff in the 'USERS' storage. I fixed that and now receive an error - " ORA-00439 feature not enabled: Deferred Segment Creation"  since a table is created with the 'SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED"